# Single quotes vs double quotes in scheme

Tags: scheme

I hope this hasn't been asked already. I saw a bunch of single vs double quotes for other languages (html, javascript, python) but can't find scheme

In scheme at the interpreter, if I type:

> (something 'x)
>   I understand that the x will be treated as an x, not evaluated to something as if it is a variable

On the other hand, if I use

> (something x)

x is evaluated as if its a variable

I know that ' is a short hand for quote (ie (quote x)) but what I don't get is how that differs from a double quote.

If I type

> "hello"
>   at the prompt, I get back "hello"

Is the only difference that the double quote keeps the quotes around the data? I've heard the double quote is like a char array, but it doesn't get evaluated and neither does the single quote, so that is the difference and when/why would I use one over the other?

Thanks all.

Comment: Double quotes denote a string literal. The single quote of quote operator will create a symbol, list or vector literal. For the complex types, each element is treated as a symbol. http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_6.html#SEC27

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Scheme, single quotes and double quotes are *entirely* different constructs. Double quotes produce a string:

```
> (string? "foo")
#t
```

Whereas the prefix operator single quote prevents an expression from being evaluated. E.g. `(+ 1 2)` evaluates to `3`, but when you single-quote it, you get a list consisting of `+`, `1` and `2`:

```
> (define three '(+ 1 2))
> three
(+ 1 2)
> (car three)
+
> (cadr three)
1
> (caddr three)
2
```

It's actually syntactic sugar for an operator called `quote`, which you can verify by quoting twice:

```
> ''foo
(quote foo)
```

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I was piecing the piece that the ' gives you back a list.. I thought it just looked like it made it a string because it didn't evaluate it. Thanks all!

Comment: @jcam77 An important distinction is that some forms are self-evaluating:  `"hello"` is the string literal `"hello"` and its value is itself.  Similarly `42` is the number `42`.  Since these are self denoting, you could also quote them if you want;  `'"hello"` produces `"hello"` and `'42` produces `42`.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that 'not evaluated' doesn't mean 'not parsed'.

Compare:

```
>'(+ a b)
(mcons '+ (mcons 'a (mcons 'b '())))

>(string->symbol "(+ 1 2)")
'|(+ 1 2)|
```